# excel is refusing the hyperlink function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to insert an hyperlink in my excelt sheet.
I tried the following example from office help page:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://example.microsoft.com/report/budport.xlsx", "Click for report")
```

Excel is complaining about an error in the formula but I can't find any.
What is wrong ?

Comment: what exactly is the error message? What is the language set in your Excel (in some countries you need to use `;` in functions instead of `,`)?

Comment: @MátéJuhász  The formula is good, but the link is bad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user was using the french version of excel with english function names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the name of the function. Since I'm using french version of excel hyperlink function become lien_hypertext (see this [link](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/LIEN-HYPERTEXTE-LIEN-HYPERTEXTE-fonction-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f))